# Create a summary table with MS SQL 2008

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

This is how I create a summary table in MySQL, how can I do the same thing in MS SQL 2008?

The idea is to create a summary table that only has dates (not time), and has summed the kWh for each meter per day.

```
CREATE table summary 
SELECT meterID, date( DateTime ) AS date, sum( kWh ) AS kWh
FROM data GROUP BY meterID, date;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for building the table your question doesn't specify exact data types.  For example is kWh only an int or could if have a decimal part.  But, taking a stab at guessing it would be something like this.

```
CREATE Table summary
(
 meterID int,
 YourDate date,
 kWh int /* or maybe a decimal(9,2) or something like that */
)
```

Then the rest is pretty close to mysql, just swapping a [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in to do the conversion.  You could also use [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but I've always liked the syntax of Cast better.

```
INSERT INTO summary (meterID, YourDate, kWh) 
(SELECT meterID, Cast(YourDateTime AS Date) AS YourDate, sum( kWh ) AS kWh
FROM data GROUP BY meterID, Cast(YourDateTime AS Date));
```

Comment: I like it, but have you got too many FROM's there?  I removed the last "FROM YourTable" and it works.

Comment: Ha, thanks for pointing that out.  It was a remnant from an edit to a prior post.  Thanks.